# Output of itertools.combinations()

Tags: python, list

I'm new to programming in python (well, programming in general), so I really hope someone could help me out a little with the using the built-in itertools.combinations function.

I am trying to create a list of all possible combinations 7 card combinations from a list of 52 cards, i.e. 52 C 7.

so my code looks something like

```
>>> import itertools
>>> deck = [1,2,3,4,5...,52]
>>> list_1 = list(itertools.combinations(deck,2))
>>> list_1[5]
(1, 7)
```

working so far, until I try the combinations of 7

```
>>> all_possible_hands = list(itertools.combinations(deck,7))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    all_possible_hands = list(itertools.combinations(deck,7))
MemoryError
```

The list can be created for smaller sets of data (52 C 2), but I get a MemoryError when the number gets larger, probably insufficient RAM. I googled how the combinations() function works, and apparently it outputs an object, which I converted into a list.

When I did without the list(), the console returned a memory address (I believe).

```
>>> all_possible_hands = itertools.combinations(deck,7)
>>> all_possible_hands
<itertools.combinations object at 0x02E63180>
```

My question is: does the memory address contain the data that I want, and can and somehow turn it into a list or something so I can access the individual elements in the list?

Thank you. Any insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are 133784560 seven-card combinations in a 52-card deck, and you are trying to create a list with 133784560 elements.  Python doesn't have enough memory to do this, and so it crashes.

`itertools.combinations` returns an iterator.  This is like a list, except it just gives you one element at a time, on demand, instead of creating them all at once.  This saves memory.  Whether you can get what you want from that iterator depends on what you want to do.  If you just want to, say, print each one, you can do that easily:

```
for item in itertools.combinations(deck, 7):
     print item
```

What you can't do so easily is get a particular item.  There is no direct equivalent of doing `list_l[5]` to get the fifth element.  You have to iterate over the iterator 5 times, or use other tools in `itertools` (like `islice`).

Comment: thank you very much. The purpose of the program can be achieved thru individual iterations, so that helps, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

This object is an [*iterator*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), returned by the [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) function `itertools.combinations`. You can access each combination by iterating over this object:

```
for hand in all_possible_hands:
     print hand
```

Iterators help to avoid keeping all the data in memory at once, but the downside is that you only access each item once. When you've finished iterating over the object, it's exhausted and you can't get anything else from it. Also, you can't access the last item without iterating till the end, unlike the usual list, etc.

You can write generator functions, too. There are examples in the [`itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). A generator function should have one or more [`yield` statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) instead of [`return` statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement).

Comment: thanks for your response, I'll have to do a bit more reading on these generator functions. Been coming across them while trying to figure this out, but they're a little bit out of my league at the moment, in time perhaps. Once again, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @user2298229 It's not a very complex concept, but may be hard to put in simple words. Reading about it in a good tutorial should help.